# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE - WHY?

Tags: php, parse-error

So I have the following code on my index.php:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); // Don't use WP themes
require('../wp-load.php'); // Allows the use of WP functions
?>

<?php // Check if the user is logged in. If not, show the login form 
global $user_ID, $user_identity; get_currentuserinfo(); if (!$user_ID) { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='login.php';</script>

    <?php } else { // If the user is logged in

        include('header.php'); ?>

        <div id="content">

            <!-- Full Width Start -->
            <div class="full-width">        
                <span class="full-width-red-left"></span>
                <div class="full-width-red-wrapper">Department Chooser</div>
                <span class="full-width-red-right"></span>           
                <div class="full-width-content">
                    <div id="panel-icons">
                        <?php // Display the menu for each department the user is a member of.
                        if(is_eventsStaff()){ eventsPanelIcon(); }
                        if(is_helpDeskStaff()){ helpPanelIcon(); }
                        if(is_hxlStaff()){ livePanelIcon(); }
                        if(is_newsStaff()){ newsPanelIcon(); }
                        if(is_raresStaff()){ raresPanelIcon(); }
                        if(is_panelAdmin()){ adminPanelIcon();} ?>       
                    </div>
                    <div id="uploader-icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="panel-horizontal-split"></div>
                        <a href="#" id="upload-panel-icon"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>           
                <div class="full-width-footer"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Full Width End -->
        </div>

    </div>  
<?php } else { echo "Test"; } }?>
```

and then header.php:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/build.css' type='text/css'/>
<title>Habbox Staff Panel</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include_once('functions.php'); // Include staff panel functions ?>

<!-- Preload Image Hovers Start -->
<img src="images/topbar_home_hover.png" class="preload" />
<img src="images/topbar_admin_hover.png" class="preload" />
<img src="images/topbar_events_hover.png" class="preload" />
<!-- Preload Image Hovers End -->

<?php if(has_Roles()) { ?>
<!-- TopBar Start -->
<div id="topbar-wrapper">
<div id="topbar-inner-wrapper">
    <span class="topbar-radio-text">Welcome <span class="bold red"><?php echo $user_login; ?></span></span> 
    <div class="topbar-divider"></div>
    <a href="<?php echo $siteURL;?>/index.php" class="topbar-home"></a>

    <?php 

    if (isset($_COOKIE['timezone'])) { date_default_timezone_set($_COOKIE['timezone']); } else { date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); }

    if(is_eventsStaff()){
        echo '<a href="'.$siteURL.'/Events/index.php" class="topbar-events"></a>';
    }

    // Check if the user is an admin
    if(is_panelAdmin()){
        echo '<a href="'.$siteURL.'/Admin/users.php" class="topbar-admin"></a>';
    }



    ?>
    <div id="topbar-logout">
        <form>
            <div class="darkbutton"><span class="darkbutton-left"></span><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Log Out</a><span class="darkbutton-right"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/Staff">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- TopBar End -->

<div id="page-wrapper">
```

but it is giving me the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in index.php on line 43

But I don't understand why. It seems to work fine if I copy the contents of header.php over in to index.php but not when I use the include.

Comment: check line number 43 in index.php and sure enough an extra closing brace. `else { echo "Test"; } }`

Comment: What if statement does the `<?php } else { echo "Test"; } }?>` at the end refer to?

Comment: Why are you spitting out a chunk of JS to redirect people instead of using an HTTP Location header?

Comment: It's not extra air4x. Line 43 is closing off the if statement from inside header.php, the 'code'<?php if(has_Roles())[ { ?>'code' and then the last } is from the index.php 'code'<?php } else { // If the user is logged in 'code'

Comment: @Tenatious The code in the included file should be in proper syntax `by itself`. So you would have to close any brace in the same file where it is opened.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want and have it so the if is in header and the close bracket in index.

Comment: Different php files have distinct statement scopes. They need to be concluded in each include script. Wrapping around file boundarys is not possible.

Comment: Why not move `} else { echo "Test"; }` into header.php. So if `if(has_Roles())` show the toolbar, `else` show `Test`.

Comment: It's okay. Found a way around it :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Reading code through `include` is not completely equivalent to copying and pasting the code. All files involved need to be valid PHP code by themselves: you cannot open an `if()` in the included file and close it in the main file. PHP will parse each file separately and find this:

```
if(...){
}else{
}else{
}
```

... which is obviously illegal.

Comment: Is there another method that is just like pasting in the code?

Comment: Just rethink your logic. It'll be better in the long term.

Comment: Yeah. Rethought my logic. Seems to work :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two else for one if:

```
if (!$user_ID) {

   <?php } else { // If the user is logged in

<?php } else { echo "Test"; } }?>
```

Comment: But there is another if in header.php

Answer (score 1):

In `header.php` you are not closing this IF:

```
<?php if(has_Roles()) { ?>
```

you can do it in this part of the code:

```
if(is_panelAdmin()){
        echo '<a href="'.$siteURL.'/Admin/users.php" class="topbar-admin"></a>';
    }

 } // Closing has_roles() IF

    ?>
```

Comment: I need it closed at the end of the page though. Not at the end of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had include wrong and each file had to be correct syntax in its self. I just put the if and else statement in the index file around the header.php include file. All seems to work :)